# How to make a bootable usb stick on Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, windows, iso

I tried to make a bootable USB stick to boot Windows in Ubuntu. I used [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/blob/master/README.md). How can I use it? I chose From a disk Win10_1909_EnglishInternational_x64.iso and file system FAT and target device /dev/sdb. When I clicked Install, the output was:

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
==============================
Error: Source media is currently mounted, unmount the partition then try again
You may now safely detach the target device
```

So how can I burn Windows 10 iso file to USB stick?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the ISO you want to use is 5,172 MiB.

The maximum possible size for a file on a FAT32 volume is 4 GiB minus 1 byte or 4,294,967,295 (232 − 1) bytes.

It won't fit.

Use NTFS on the USB Flash Drive instead.